# grep with double quotation in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, grep, double-quotes

I'm trying to find IPs from whitelist IP list for nginx configuration.

`/tmp/iplist`:

```
11.2.3.4
22.2.3.4
```

`/tmp/whitelist`:

```
"1.2.3.4"
"11.2.3.4"
"1.2.3.44"
"11.2.3.44"
```

And when I run grep like `grep '"11.2.3.4"' /tmp/whitelist`, I can get a right answer like `"11.2.3.4"`.

However, within a bash script, I could not get any answers.
Here are some patterns that I tried:

`/tmp/findIPs.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ip in $(cat /tmp/iplist)
do
  grep '"$ip"' /tmp/whitelist
  grep '\"$ip\"' /tmp/whitelist
  grep '\\\"$ip\\\"' /tmp/whitelist
  x="\"$ip\""
  fgrep '$x' /tmp/whitelist
  grep '$x' /tmp/whitelist
  y="$ip"
  fgrep '$y' /tmp/whitelist
  grep '$y' /tmp/whitelist
```

And, this is a result, which is blank.

```
> bash /tmp/findIPs.sh
>
```

What is the point that I missing?

Comment: `grep "1.2.3.4"` will match `1928374`, since `.` is a wildcard in regex syntax. You probably want a parameter such as `-F` to specify to grep that its argument is to be treated as a literal string to search for rather than as a regular expression.

Comment: that said, it's noteworthy that *all* of your attempts appear to be using syntactic single quotes, and thus all of them are making the same basic mistake.

Comment: BTW, if your goal is to find lines in common between two files, there are **much** more efficient ways to do it (requiring only a single-pass, if you're willing to sort).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for your comment. I originally used fgrep (there were more tried patterns). Anyway, unfortunately the two file should conserve different format: one should have double quotation when the other does not. Therefore I did not used sorting or  `-f` option. (`-f` option may be useful with other manipulation of expression, but I have no idea about it.)

Comment: The format difference is a pretty small one. If you use a process substitution, as in `fgrep -f <(sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' </tmp/iplist) /tmp/whitelist`, that should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest adaptation of the code you're using is:

```
for ip in $(cat /tmp/iplist)
do
    grep "$ip" /tmp/whitelist
done
```

Once you've got the value in the variable, its double quotes aren't damaged by further double-quoted variable expansion.  If the `/tmp/iplist` file doesn't contain the double quotes but they're critical, then you can use:

```
grep "\"$ip\"" /tmp/whitelist
```

or you could use this:

```
grep \""$ip"\" /tmp/whitelist
```

(and there are two asymmetric permutations available too).  It's a good idea to make sure you do know why that works.  There are some ways to use single quotes if you want to, but the `"$ip"` part must be outside of the single quotes.

All your examples start the pattern argument to `grep` with a single quote.  Single quotes suppress all expansions until the next single quote.  So, for example, `grep '"$ip"' /tmp/whitelist` is looking for 5 characters — `"`, `$`, `i`, `p`, `"` — in the file.  In none them is the variable `ip` ever expanded.

There will be problems if any IP address ever gets a space in it.  Be cautious about using `for ip in $(cat /tmp/iplist)`.  Very often you'd do better with:

```
while read -r ip
do
    grep "$ip" /tmp/whitelist
done < /tmp/iplist
```

Another way to do this is with `grep -F` or `fgrep`:

```
grep -F -f /tmp/iplist /tmp/whitelist
```

This doesn't insist on double quotes around the IP addresses, but makes a single pass over the `/tmp/whitelist` file (and a single pass over the `/tmp/iplist` file too), which is about as efficient as it gets. This will produce lines in a slightly different order from before, which probably won't matter, but you should be aware of it.

If you must have the double quotes (to avoid selecting `11.2.3.44` when searching for `11.2.3.4`, then:

```
grep -F -f <(sed 's/^/"/; s/$/"/' /tmp/iplist) /tmp/whitelist
```

This uses [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to pass an edited version of the `/tmp/iplist` file to the `grep` command.  If you don't have process substitution in your shell, you can probably use:

```
sed 's/^/"/; s/$/"/' /tmp/iplist | grep -F -f - /tmp/whitelist
```

which makes `grep` read the list of patterns to match from standard input instead of a named file.  If perchance `-f -` doesn't work (e.g. because you're working on a Mac using macOS, or probably a BSD machine), then `-f /dev/stdin` probably will, or `-f /dev/fd/0`.

You could also generate the `/tmp/iplist` file with the double quotes in place.  You could generate the `/tmp/whitelist` file without the double quotes and then use `grep -x` to specify an exact match.

In case you haven't already gathered, there are quite a lot of different ways to do this.

Comment: I'd say there's no reason to ever use the `for` loop. The `while` loop is only 2 characters longer (well, 6 or so, you should also use `IFS= read -r`), and has none of the drawbacks of the `for` loop.

Comment: Was going to say -- I'd suggest putting the best-practice example *first*, if you feel some compulsion to leave the incorrect one in at all.

Comment: that said -- the OP appears to be intending to search for *literal* double quotes within their data, so we probably want `grep "\"$ip\""`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That wasn't a response to you; your comment popped up just as I was hitting enter.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, there are only preexisting double quotes in the values in `/tmp/whitelist`, not in `/tmp/iplist`, as given in the question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for your pointing. I changed my code like `fgrep "\"$ip\""`, and it works.

Comment: @QuietJoon, ...note that the `while read` approach advised here is definitely preferable. See also [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).